# Builder design pattern with no base class/interface for product classes

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, builder

The GoF book states that product classes in builder pattern does not necessarily need to inherit from a base class. The concrete builder classes may produce entirely different products which share same abstract construction steps.

The client using builder pattern needs to instantiate concrete builder class and associate the  object with Director object. The director would use the builder to build the object and return the complete object finally.

My question is how would the director be designed if product classes would not share same base class? In C# this can be easily implemented with using generics but a design pattern does not depend on language features. Defining separate methods for each type of concrete product does not seem good idea as it will tightly couple the director with product class and any new product class will require a change in director class.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern doesn't care about the nature of the Product, so you can certainly just return Object if you have Builders that produce different types of Products.  The result is no longer statically typed, but that's the consumer's problem now, since they've asked for a Director to use Builders who can produce arbitrary Products.